# How to display corresponding values of a selected item of list box that is linked to a mysql table to a textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

The list box only displays values of the first column of the table(but the has 3 columns i.e Name, Username and Password). [Like this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9mnR.png)This is the code :

```
private void listbox_user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(con))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Name=@name";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listbox_user.SelectedItem.ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    txtbox_name.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
                    txtbox_username.Text = dr["Username"].ToString();
                    txtbox_pwd.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to display all three column values in their respective text boxes. But when I click the listbox items, but the textbox do not get filled. There is no error displayed though.

Comment: How do you fill the ListBox originating the username through SelectedItem?

Comment: I used the DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                sqlda.Fill(dtbl);
                listbox_user.DataSource = dtbl;
                listbox_user.DisplayMember = "Name";
                listbox_user.ValueMember = "Username";

Comment: No any solutions?

Comment: What was wrong in the answer I have posted?

Comment: The ValueMember property is UserName, so your query should search for UserName (not Name) when you use the SelectedValue property to retrieve the ListBox currently selected item